# Show all records with an invalid picklist value

Tags: picklist, data

Is there a simple way to reveal records that have incorrect picklist values?

Example:

- Record A is created with restricted value Picklist__c value of
  "Aerospace"
- Picklist__c is updated months later and the value
  "Aerospace" is no longer an option. No data cleanse of records was done.

How can I easily tell Record A will hit errors if we try to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Salesforce has recently made a change, then there isn't a way to programatically retrieve the "active" values of a picklist.

The approach I'd probably take here is to manually gather your valid picklist values (by looking at the field metadata in the Object Manager of the web UI), and create a temporary formula field to compare your picklist value against the valid values (you may need to incorporate record type in there as well).

That'll give you an easy true/false that you could filter on with SOQL or export for external processing.

I think the `CASE()` function would be a good fit here, something like

```
1 = CASE(
        TEXT(MyPicklist),
        "Picklist Value 1", 1,
        ...
        "Picklist Value N", 1,
        0 /* If the picklist value matches none of the valid values, return 0 */
    )
/* The end result is 1 = 1, or 1 = 0, which will give you true/false as a result */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

- an export of all records for the object via Data Loader. Export the Id field and the picklist field
- an update of all records and only map the ID field using Data Loader
- Data Loader would then report as errors all records that need to be migrated to valid values

Of course, this presumes your triggers and other automations are idempotent or you have a way to disable all automation via a running user's hierarchical custom settings